# Where can I find the error logs of nginx, using FastCGI and Django?

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi, error-log

I'm using Django with [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) + nginx. Where are the logs (errors) stored in this case?

Answer (score 584, accepted):

Errors are stored in the nginx log file. You can specify it in the root of the nginx configuration file:

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log  warn;
```

On Mac OS X with [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29), the log file was found by default at the following location:

```
/usr/local/var/log/nginx
```

Comment: That's maybe version dependent but my log is inside: `/opt/nginx/logs/error.log`

Comment: on Mac OS X with homebrew: /usr/local/var/log/nginx. see lfender's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27402568/576767)

Comment: On ubuntu I have it in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`. It is best to check the `nginx.conf` file and find the `error_log` setting.

Comment: Found mine at /opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/error.log lol. Currently on macOS 13 (Ventura). Also seems you could run `nginx -h` to view the default log output directory.

Answer (score 343):

I was looking for a different solution.

Error logs, by default, before any configuration is set, on my system (x86 [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)), was found in:

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: Apparently this is configureable only at compile time with the `--error-log-path` compile option http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/147

Comment: on raspberry pi3 its the location

Answer (score 203):

You can use `lsof` (list of open files) in most cases to find open log files without knowing the configuration.

**Example:**

Find the PID of `httpd` (the same concept applies for nginx and other programs):

```
$ ps aux | grep httpd
...
root     17970  0.0  0.3 495964 64388 ?        Ssl  Oct29   3:45 /usr/sbin/httpd
...
```

Then search for open log files using `lsof` with the PID:

```
$ lsof -p 17970 | grep log
httpd   17970 root    2w   REG             253,15     2278      6723 /var/log/httpd/error_log
httpd   17970 root   12w   REG             253,15        0      1387 /var/log/httpd/access_log
```

If `lsof` prints nothing, even though you expected the log files to be found, issue the same command using `sudo`.

You can read a little more [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110192939/http://slash4.net/blog/howto/find-log-file-location-of-linux-process-with-lsof.html).

Comment: it's a nice trick to remember.. no guessing any more where the log files could be

Comment: this taught me how to fish; wish I could upvote more

Comment: +1 For an answer on how to look. I was looking for logs from a different installation of nginx and it wasn't in the top answer.

Comment: you can poke at similar data on linux in the `/proc` filesystem. `/proc/${pid}/fd` has symlinks to the open files, pipes, devices, etc

Comment: while using [$ ps aux | grep httpd] I got =auto httpd (in red). do you know what it means please?

Answer (score 123):

Run this command, to check error logs:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Answer (score 44):

My ngninx logs are located here:

```
/usr/local/var/log/nginx/*
```

You can also check your `nginx.conf` to see if you have any directives dumping to custom log.

run `nginx -t` to locate your `nginx.conf`.

```
# in ngingx.conf
error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;
error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
error_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log  info;
```

Nginx is usually set up in `/usr/local` or `/etc/`. The server could be configured to dump logs to `/var/log` as well.

If you have an alternate location for your nginx install and all else fails, you could use the `find` command to locate your file of choice.

`find /usr/ -path "*/nginx/*" -type f -name '*.log'`, where `/usr/` is the folder you wish to start searching from.

Comment: The logs will be here if you installed Nginx with Homebrew.

Answer (score 25):

Logs location on Linux servers:

```
Apache – /var/log/httpd/

IIS – C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

Node.js – /var/log/nodejs/

nginx – /var/log/nginx/

Passenger – /var/app/support/logs/

Puma – /var/log/puma/

Python – /opt/python/log/

Tomcat – /var/log/tomcat8
```

Answer (score 11):

For **Mac OS** users, you can type `nginx -help` in your terminal.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.21.0
Usage: nginx [-?hvVtTq] [-s signal] [-p prefix]
             [-e filename] [-c filename] [-g directives]

Options:
  -?,-h         : this help
  -v            : show version and exit
  -V            : show version and configure options then exit
  -t            : test configuration and exit
  -T            : test configuration, dump it and exit
  -q            : suppress non-error messages during configuration testing
  -s signal     : send signal to a master process: stop, quit, reopen, reload
  -p prefix     : set prefix path (default: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/nginx/1.21.0/)
  -e filename   : set error log file (default: /opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/error.log)
  -c filename   : set configuration file (default: /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)
  -g directives : set global directives out of configuration file
```

Then, you could find some default path for configuration and log files, in this case:

```
/opt/homebrew/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: why is this different for different users? For me it is in ```opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/error.log```. Doesnt make any sense

Answer (score 10):

Type this command in the terminal:

```
sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: That is not an answer and should be a comment instead. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
cd /var/log/nginx/
cat error.log
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to set where the access log should be in nginx configuring file . Using acces_log /path/ Like this.

```
keyval $remote_addr:$http_user_agent $seen zone=clients;

server { listen 443 ssl;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers   HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

if ($seen = "") {
    set $seen  1;
    set $logme 1;
}
access_log  /tmp/sslparams.log sslparams if=$logme;
error_log  /pathtolog/error.log;
# ...
}
```