# Blank page on update after including if condition yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

When I include **if condition** in update form I'm getting blank page.
Otherwise without **if condition** update works fine.

_form.php without **if condition** (this works fine)

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'certified')->radioList(['y'=>'YES', 'n'=>'NO'])  ?>

     <div class="row">  
      <div class="row">            
        <?= $form->field($modelcertificate, 'description')->dropDownList(
                    ArrayHelper::map(CertificateDescription::find()->all(),'description','description'),
                    [   'prompt'=>'select desc', 
                    ]); ?>    
      </div>

       <div class="row">

     <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q1')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

      </div>
  </div>
```

For the same if I include If condition, after hitting update button blank page will be shown.

_form.php with **if condition** ( leads to blank page)

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'certified')->radioList(['y'=>'YES', 'n'=>'NO'])  ?>

     <div class="row">  
      <?php if ($model->certified == 'y') : ?>  
        <div class="row">              
           <?= $form->field($modelcertificate, 'description')->dropDownList(
               ArrayHelper::map(CertificateDescription::find()->all(),'description','description'),
                                    ['prompt'=>'select desc', ]); ?>       
         </div>
      <?php else: ?>
         <div class="row">
        <?= $form->field($modelqm, 'q1')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
```

Comment: Check for reason in log file.

Comment: It says **[yii\web\HttpException:404] yii\web\NotFoundHttpException: The requested page does not exist.**

Comment: But how come it works fine when if condition is not there??\

Comment: No, it's not this error.

Comment: It;s not logged, I don't find any

Comment: Update your if condition without space like this <?php if($model->certified == 'y'): ?>

Comment: The if condition evaluates to false, since at the moment of rendering the file the `certified` field does not have a value. The problem might be in the controller.

Comment: Look at web server error.log. If you use Apache, [they might be here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39008)

Comment: Also, try to simplify you `if` condition. Replace it with `if(true):`. and if this works, you might be sure - problem is in `certified` field.

Comment: @Irfan Ali, No change after removing the space

Comment: @gmc, I'm facing this problem during update and in create action I have made it to mandatory to select one option, so there is no way the certified field being null or empty. (Create and update have different forms and in create form there is no if condition, I have included only in the update form)

Comment: @wormi4ok, I'am using NGINX

Comment: @wormi4ok If I replace it with` if(true):` and remove the `else` condition it is working but with `else` condition it will lead to blank page

Comment: In case you use Nginx, examine its error.log. Location [should be specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706111/where-can-i-find-the-error-logs-of-nginx-using-fastcgi-and-django) in you server configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141700/discussion-between-rachna-and-wormi4ok).

Comment: Checked it, I don't find anything related to update
can placing of <div> and if statement lead to this type of behavior??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in Controller, so **blank page** is caused by missing return point.

For debug purposes it possible to use [CRUD](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html#generating-crud) generated by `gii`, and improve it line by line to fit your personal needs.