# Django Ajax post failed with Gunicorn and Nginx on AWS

Tags: ajax, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I am writing a app using AJAX deployed by gunicorn and nginx on AWS.
It works very well when I am using `python3 manage.py runserver`. But after I used gunicorn, the AJAX post doesn't work. I get a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

What I did is a very simple AJAX post

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/analytical-tools/getData/',
                data: {
                  'somedata':somedata
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                   /*do something*/
                }
});
```

First I want to ask is is there any difference on AJAX when deployed on Gunicorn?
And I want to ask how to debug on gunicorn. The gunicorn runs in the background and I can't see any debug information or print something when it is running.

Answer (score 0):

`404` stand for not found... and here is the question is the django endpoint available at all or not available for certain data?

1) if at all  mayby the config nginx/gunicorn is problematic

2) if for certain data make sure this data are really there

3) idea make sure there is no crap in JS, e.g have a look into XHR section and copy the request load, and cross validate it in Postman

Regarding debuging, there should be files in logs with each request etc.

**where uwsgi**? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/where-s-my-django-application-log-file

**where nginx**? [Where can I find the error logs of nginx, using fastcgi and django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706111/where-can-i-find-the-error-logs-of-nginx-using-fastcgi-and-django)